# SignalR Newtonsoft out of memory exception

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, исключения

Разрабатываю систему чаттинга на ASP.NET MVC используя SignalR, посылаю на фронт через метод Clients.Caller.onConnected много сообщений и комментариев.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        string id = Context.ConnectionId;

        string name = currentUser.ChatName;

        var messages = (from user in context.Users
                       join message in context.Messages on user.Id equals message.UserId
                       select new { user.ChatName, user.Photo, message.MessageText, message.Id}).ToList();


        var comments = (from coment in context.Comments
                       join user in context.Users on coment.UserId equals user.Id
                       select new { user.ChatName, user.Photo, coment.CommentText, coment.Id, coment.MessageId }).ToList();

        if (Users.Values.All(x => x != name))
        {
            Users.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);
            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, name, Users, messages, comments);// Вот здесь вылазит exception
            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, name);
        }    
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Первая загрузка страницы происходит нормально. После перезагрузки с метода onConnected вылазит ексепшн - An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code. Возможно кто-то сталкивался, может как-то оптимизировать json ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сколько данный и каким отправляется? если уменьшить размер данных ошибка уходит?

Comment: Да, если сообщений и комментариев не много примерно до 20 ти

Comment: как выглядят посылаемые объекты?

Comment: Прикрепил к вопросу, комментарии по той же схеме

Comment: ооооооооооооооооооооооо, я вижу фото. попробуй убрать это поле при посылке

Comment: и добавь еще описание классов кодом, а не картинкой

Comment: Но мне нужно именно отправлять base64 фото на фронт. Описание каких классов?

Comment: что такое `Users`, `messages`, `comments`

Comment: _Но мне нужно именно отправлять base64 фото на фронт_ - просто попробуй убрать, и посмотреть исчезнет ли ошибка. судя по скрину каждая фотография занимает чуть больше мегабайта, это не так уж и мало особенно когда их сотни

Comment: Да, ты прав, после убирания все норм, но как мне быть, ограничить размер фото?

Comment: сколько элементов в посылаемом списке?

Comment: Если ты про Users то это Dictionary, 2 элемента ConnectionId и ChatName юзера

Comment: я про `messages` и `comments`: сколько элементов в каждом из этих списков?

Comment: messages - 4, comments - 5

Comment: не может быть, у тебя на скрине как минимум 29 элементов показано

Comment: Сообщений 54, комментов 16

Comment: вообще подход мне не очень нравится: какой смысл слать в сообщении кучу одинаковых полей? проще в message вставлять UserId, а уже на клиенте по этому UserId из коллекции пользователей получать и chatName и Photo

Comment: сейчас у тебя получается даже если сообщения от одного пользователя: 70 мегабайт пытается послаться вместо одного

Comment: Не много не понял, создать метод на серве, который принимает на вход UserID и возвращает коллекцию юзеров и обращаться по нему через фронт?

Comment: это один из вариантов. второй. в дополнение слать список пользователей на клиент и на клиенте уже разбираться